# Visually summarizing string data

Tags: data-visualization, large-data

I have a distance metric on a collection of strings on the order of tens of thousands. What would be an intuitive way to summarize how 'different' these strings are or when they overlap?

My goal is to visually ensure high entropy and be able to recognize clustering regions and the strings associated with it.

I envision a kind of clustering plot where there is some radius around each string which captures its neighbors.... but this requires having a meaningful coordinate system.

Comment: What's a 1-dimensional string? How is it different from an $n$-dimensional string? Are these strings natural language (e.g. news articles or books or tweets) or are they some other kind of string like GATTACA? For natural language, you might be interested in [tag:word-embeddings] which are then summarized for each document using e.g. the coordinate-wise mean.

Comment: They are nucleotides generated with some underlying bias. Removed the tautology.